# chromedp click is not working in my golang code. can you find what's wrong?

Tags: go, click, scrape, chromedp

I'm working on scrapper with chromedp.

To get what i want (page html), i have to click a specific button.

So I used chromedp.click, and chromedp.outerhtml, but i only got html of page before click, not the html of page after click have done.

Can you see my code and advice me how to fix it?

```
func runCrawler(URL string, lineNum string, stationNm string) {
    
        // settings for crawling
    opts := append(chromedp.DefaultExecAllocatorOptions[:],
        chromedp.Flag("headless", false))
    
        // create chrome instance
    contextVar, cancelFunc := chromedp.NewExecAllocator(context.Background(), opts...)
    defer cancelFunc()

    contextVar, cancelFunc = chromedp.NewContext(contextVar)
    defer cancelFunc()


    var htmlContent string

    err := chromedp.Run(contextVar,
        chromedp.Navigate(URL),
        chromedp.WaitVisible(".end_footer_area"),
        chromedp.Click(".end_section.station_info_section > div.at_end.sofzqce > div > div.c10jv2ep.wrap_btn_schedule.schedule_time > button"),
        chromedp.OuterHTML("html", &htmlContent, chromedp.ByQuery),
    )
    fmt.Println("html", htmlContent)
    checkErr(err)
```

i also give you homepage and button i need to click

Page URL: https://pts.map.naver.com/end-subway/ends/web/11321/home

Button Area I need to click:

[image: [enter image description here]]

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page you want to get is open in a new tab (target).

In this case, we can use [chromedp.WaitNewTarget](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/chromedp/chromedp#WaitNewTarget) to create a chan from where we can receive the target id of the new tab. Then create a new context with the [chromedp.WithTargetID](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/chromedp/chromedp#WithTargetID) option so that we can connect to the new tab. From here everything is what you are already familiar with.

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "strings"

    "github.com/chromedp/cdproto/target"
    "github.com/chromedp/chromedp"
)

func main() {
    opts := append(chromedp.DefaultExecAllocatorOptions[:],
        chromedp.Flag("headless", false),
    )

    ctx, cancel := chromedp.NewExecAllocator(context.Background(), opts...)
    defer cancel()

    ctx, cancel = chromedp.NewContext(ctx)
    defer cancel()

    var htmlContent string

    ch := chromedp.WaitNewTarget(ctx, func(i *target.Info) bool {
        return strings.Contains(i.URL, "/timetable/web/")
    })

    err := chromedp.Run(ctx,
        chromedp.Navigate("https://pts.map.naver.com/end-subway/ends/web/11321/home"),
        chromedp.WaitVisible(".end_footer_area"),
        chromedp.Click(".end_section.station_info_section > div.at_end.sofzqce > div > div.c10jv2ep.wrap_btn_schedule.schedule_time > button"),
    )
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    newCtx, cancel := chromedp.NewContext(ctx, chromedp.WithTargetID(<-ch))
    defer cancel()

    if err := chromedp.Run(newCtx,
        chromedp.WaitReady(".table_schedule", chromedp.ByQuery),
        chromedp.OuterHTML("html", &htmlContent, chromedp.ByQuery),
    ); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("html", htmlContent)
}
```

Comment: Yup it works! Thank you so much. You save my life...